# chmod + change owner on all files under folder

Tags: linux, files, permissions, rhel, chmod

I have very strange issue

when we perform the following ( change owner from bash script ) on our redhat machine

```
chmod 600 /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
```

we get:

```
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-94-redhat.repo’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-94-redhat.repo’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-94-redhat.repo’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-94-redhat.repo’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-94-redhat.repo’: No such file or directory
```

but file exsist under /etc/yum.repo.d

```
yum.repos.d]# ls -ltr
```

-rw-------. 1 root root 482 Mar 29  2016 pgdg-94-redhat.repo

so how it can be - what is going here ?

Comment: Use `chown` to change ownership, `chmod` to change permissions.  Are the files that you trying to run `chmod` on actually symbolic links, and if so, do they link to _existing files_?

Answer (score 2):

As Hauke mentioned, SELinux is likely the issue.  Are you trying to change the permissions to a different user/mode?  ls -lZ will give you the file with the particular selinux context.

An example would be:

```
rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       rhel-source.repo
```

if the context isn't right, it won't work.
in this case, `# restorecon /etc/yum.repos.d/*` will fix the contexts.

As far as your script goes, at the end, you should probably do the restorecon command on the /etc/yum.repos.d directory to ensure the contexts on the repo files are correct.  The OS will then work with them.

Answer (score 0):

The dot at the end of `-rw-------.` shows that there is an SELinux security context for this file. And given the result it probably blocks the access.

Comment: so how we can avoid this error?

Comment: @yael You have to reconfigure SELinux. But I am not familiar with it so I cannot tell you how to do that. You might ask a new question here. One obvious question is: Who configured that? Maybe that is a default configuration.